# how to save calculated field in a useState Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the problem in how do I make the total field of my useState to be saved or loaded with the calculation of price * quantity, I am already saving in my useState the price and quantity but I am not able to save the total.

here is my code.

import React, { Fragment,useState } from 'react';

const DetailPurchase =(props) => {
const [detail, setDetail] = useState({
price: 0.00,
quantity: 0,
total:0.00,
});

```
const updateState = e => {
    setDetail({
        ...detail,
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
}

return(
    <Fragment>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <form onSubmit={addDetail}
                        >
                           <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Price</label>
                                <input class="form-control"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="price"
                                        onChange={updateState}/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Quantity</label>
                                <input class="form-control"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="quantity"
                                        onChange={updateState}/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="btn btn-success btn-block " 
                                        type="submit"
                                        value="Add"

                                />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </Fragment>
)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having it be computed after the state hook like this

```
const [detail, setDetail] = useState({price: 0, quantity: 0 });
const total = useMemo(() => detail.price * detail.quantity, [detail]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alejandro for answering, the calculation is fine but I need to have that total in the detail object const [detail, setDetail] = useState({price: 0, quantity: 0, total: 0 });

Comment: @alexander Can you possibly explain why you need it to be that way and can't have it on a separate state? I think you are overthinking the approach.

Answer (score -2):

Use formik https://formik.org/
Its better in forms and input fields and u can change the change handlers